# No puedo poner una imagen correctamente en alertController

Tags: css, angular, ionic, scss

Tengo una alerta, que muestra una imagen para, principalmente, poderle hacer un tipo de zoom, esta alerta con la imagen me va de maravilla, me gusta como se. Sin embargo, queriendo hacer un poco mas grande la alerta para que se muestre mas grande la imagen, solo los bordes se hacen mas grandes

---

### [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver, el borde, donde debería de terminar es abajo del botón, y por mas que modifico el global.scss no consigo hacer que los bordes se reduzcan, incluso cuando lo consigo, hace que la imagen se vea **super** pequeña

```
.toast-custom-class {
    --width: 550%;
    --height: 350px;
    --border-radius: 3px;
    --background:rgba(79, 79, 79, 0.75);
 }
```

Y lo que tengo en mi .ts es

```
    let imagen = 'http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-2YKV1axQpxU/VQqC-rExXYI/AAAAAAAAA8Y/_ZFG08Avly0/s1600/Plaquica3.jpg'//Imagen solo de ejemplo
      const showImage = await this.alertController.create({
        message: `<img src="${ imagen}">`,
        buttons: ['Close'],
        cssClass: "toast-custom-class",
        animated: true,
        keyboardClose: true,
        mode: "md",
      });
      await showImage.present();
```

No conozco mucho de css por lo que agradezco sii alguien me puede ayudar

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar incrustarle css a la imagen que le pasas:

```
message: `<img style="width: 100% !important; height: 100% !important" src="${ imagen}">`,
```